# Discord.py bot.command stopped working after usage of on_message

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a script with both bot.command and bot.event but for some reason only bot.command is working

bot.command and bot.event work separately but not together for some reason

Here is the code:

```
# bot.py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

TOKEN = ('token')
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',')



@bot.event

async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if foo:
        await message.channel.send("foo")


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def foo(ctx, args):
    foo = bot.get_user(args)
    await ctx.send(foo)








bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `on_message` you need to process your bot's commands:

```py
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Also you do not need to use `pass_context=True` anymore, it is always passed now.